# How to remove only one media rule property from external css

Tags: css, media-queries

I have bootstrap.min.css, which defines:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) .modal-dialog {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 30px auto; 
}

@media (min-width: 992px) .modal-lg {
    width: 900px;
}
```

I want width: auto; for "modal-dialog modal-lg" screens between 768 to 992px. So I try in my css:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) .modal-dialog {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

but this does not applies.

Then, I googled something like this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  body .modal-dialog {
      width: auto !important;
  }
}
```

But this overrides also @media (min-width: 992px). How to override only (min-width: 768px) rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This media query should achieve what you asked. You set the minimum AND the maximum width where to apply the desired changes.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
    .modal-dialog {
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

`!important` should not be necessary unless you have to overwrite another `!important` :)